# Weak Interruptions

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions

What is a weak interruption and more importantly, how do I recognize it?

According to the page below, these are weak interruptions

> If the break is weak, do not use comma(s).
>
> > Anna called to say her car would not start. Rafael will ***therefore*** have
> >     to walk to school.
>
> Weak interruption = no commas.
>
> > The long noodles splashed tomato sauce all over the front of Brenda's
> >     shirt. Ordering fettuccine was a mistake ***indeed***.
>
> Weak interruption = no comma.

How is the interruption below from the same page different from the above?

> After mowing the yard in the hot sun, Pedro was too hungry to shower.
>   He did wash his dusty hands, ***however***.

I do not think you make weak or strong interruption simply by removing or adding a comma.

Note: I read on another website that a weak interruption is a non-restrictive clause, or non-essential information. The examples above, however, do not show any clauses of that sort.

Source: [The Conjunctive Adverb. Recognize a conjunctive adverb when you see one](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/conjunctiveadverb.htm)

Comment: It's not really a technical term and it probably doesn't really have a precise definition.  It seems like more of a bit of subjective writing advice from the author than a grammatical description, so if you don't find it useful personally, I'd just ignore it and move on.

Comment: Commas simply mirror the way a sentence might be spoken out loud.  What your text calls a "strong interruption" simply means that there would be a pause between one word and the next, to indicate a change in the direction of conversation.  In most of these cases this is up to individual style to decide whether to pause or not.

Answer (score 1):

Commas simply mirror the way a sentence might be spoken out loud. What your text calls a "strong interruption" simply means that there would be a pause between one word and the next, to indicate a change in the direction of conversation. In most of these cases this is up to individual style to decide whether to pause or not.

Both of these are correct:

> She told me she was not friends with him, but I'm pretty sure I saw her talking to him, outside the cafeteria.
>
> She told me she was not friends with him but I'm pretty sure I saw her talking to him outside the cafeteria.

Commas often serve no function other than to make a sentence easier to read.